# Ember.js / Rails and associations: how to submit back to Rails a record and its associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, ember-data

Say you have two Rails models with association:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :moo
end

class Moo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :foos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :foos
end
```

Thanks to ActiveModel::Serializer it is easy to send existing nested objects from Rails to Ember.js. But I can't find a way to create such nested objects in Ember and send them back to Rails for persistence. My understanding is Ember needs to send back something like:

```
"moo"=> {
   "foos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name" => ...}},
   "name" => ...
}
```

Is there a "standard" way to do that? I have seen a few "old" questions on this subject but no real solution, and since Ember has been changing so much I thought there might be a simple way to do it now (without changing the Rest Adapter itself).

Thanks a lot,
PJ

Comment: You can use ember-data for it. Here, read about relations in ember-data.
http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-one

Comment: Thanks Nikita. Unfortunately it does not really work... I know about the Rest adapter and the fact you can include nested records. But it won't let you submit just one POST to the server for both the parent record and nested ones. It always fires multiple POST - at least I haven't found a way to do it. So it won't work with Rails if you use accepts_nested_attributes_for on the Rails side.

Comment: Same situation with mongoDB embedded documents.

Comment: You can check the `bulkCommit` setting of REST Adapter.

Comment: I did try bulkCommit - it did not work. Still two POST to the server. Does it work for you?

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but I know single POST to take nested attributes works with AngularJS if single post is critical and you can't get it to work in Ember. Here is something close to what we use internally: https://github.com/garysweaver/restful_json

Comment: Thanks guys. In case it helps, someone has put together a Relational Adapter for Ember. It has been working well for us: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/724

Answer (score 2):

I have just modified the params before handing them to `create` or `update_attributes` methods like this:

```
  line_items = params[:invoice].delete(:line_items) #Ember format
  params[:invoice][:line_items_attributes] = line_items
```